# Turning dictonary values to string to put into textfile?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gps

I am using a raspberry pi B+ with a GPS module to output GPS details to a textfile.

Here are some links to understand the attributes in use:

http://python3-microstacknode.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example.html#l80-gps
http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/

Here is my code:

```
##Prints the latitude and longitude every second.
import time
import microstacknode.hardware.gps.l80gps

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gps = microstacknode.hardware.gps.l80gps.L80GPS()
    while True:
        data = gps.get_gpgga()
        print(data.values())
        text_file = open("/home/pi/fyp/gps.txt", "w")
        text_file.write(data.values())
        text_file.close()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Here is my output:

```
$GPGGA,012939.800,,,,,0,0,,,M,,M,,*40

dict_values(['', '', '', '0', '', 12939.8, '0', 0.0, '$GPGGA', 0.0, '', '', ''])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gps.py", line 11, in <module>
    text_file.write(data.values())
TypeError: must be str, not dict_values
```

How do I get the output to be put into a textfile?

Comment: As the error message says, it must be of type `str`, meaning a string. Did you try Googling something like "python turn object into string"?

Comment: Why do you open the and close the file in the loop? Do you need the file to hold only one entry?

Answer (score 0):

```
text_file.write(",".join(map(str,data.values())))
```

Just do a `join` on `,`

Comment: it now gives TypeError: sequence item 5: expected str instance, float found

Comment: @JolyDroneSP - Are you making any attempt whatsoever to read and understand the error messages you're getting?

Comment: @JolyDroneSP check edit...you need to convert all to `str`

Comment: @vks it now gives  File "gps.py", line 12
    text_file.close()
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @JolyDroneSP dats a diff line!!!!!!also you should open file in `append` mode as all data will be cleared in the loop